# Mostrar Check Marcado en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Tengo un valor de un checkbox guardado en la base de datos (tabla = way, campo = active, valores 1 = Activo, 0 = Inactivo, campo booleano), pero cuando se requiere actualizar el formulario y se abre, no muestra el check marcado, siempre lo deja desmarcado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label col-md-push-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="checkbox">                               
                                <label>
                                    <?php
                                    $sqlprueba = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM way");
                                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlprueba);
                                    $check = $row['active'];
                                    if ($check == 1) {
                                        echo " checked";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <input type = "checkbox" name = "mod_active" value = "<?php echo $row['active']; ?>"<?php echo $check;
                                    ?>Activo <?php echo $row['active']; ?>

                                </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya imprimio en consolo que valor te esta trayendo  $row['active'] ??

Comment: En el archivo .js tienes que colocar el atributo checked como true y así poder visualizar en el checkbox el chequeo, lo puedes hacer con jquery : $(this).prop('checked',false);

Comment: Ya vi mejor tu código. Aquí: `$check = $row['active'] === 1 ? " checked" : "";` estás haciendo una **comparación estricta** al usar `===`, sólo será verdadero si el valor que hay en `$row['active'] ` es del tipo `integer`. Es muy probable que ese valor sea del tipo `string`. Prueba de este modo: **`$check = $row['active'] == 1 ? " checked" : "";`** Si sigue sin funcionar, por favor muestra lo que hay en el valor mediante: `var_dump($row["active"]);`

Comment: Si ya imprimí y me sale checked y ya hice el cambio pero tampoco lo muestra marcado

Comment: Soy como nuevo en esto y no se como hacerlo con Jquery

Comment: ¿Tú quieres mostrar uno o varios `checkbox`?. Actualmente sólo se muestra uno, y adquiere el estado del último valor que haya en el `while`. No sé si te has dado cuenta de eso.

Comment: Es solo 1 checkbox

Comment: Entonces no entiendo qué sentido tiene el `while`. El cual recorrerá todos los resultados, dejando, el estado del checkbox según el último dato que encuentra en los resultados. Este código también es confuso, trato de escribirlo en sólo PHP y no le encuentro la vuelta: `<input type = "checkbox" name = "mod_active" value = "<?php echo $row['active']; ?>"<?php echo $check; ?>Activo <?php echo $row['active']; ?>` la mezcla de HTML/PHP produce código ilegible y complicado de analizar.

Comment: Ya lo modifique le puse un if

Comment: El `if` no mejora nada. Tu código es incoherente. Seleccionas todo de la base de datos sin ningún filtro ni criterio y luego tomas un resultado de esos que vienen en la consulta, el cual ni siquiera sabes cuál es, para modificar el estado del checkbox. No hay una precisión en lo que estás haciendo. Tu consulta debería tener algo como un `WHERE`... algo como `SELECT * FROM way WHERE id=1`, ahí ya sabemos que vamos a trabajar con el id 1, y no con cualquier registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $ccheck = '';  
    if ($check == 1) $ccheck = 'checked';
    ...
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "mod_active" value = "<?php echo $row['active']; ?>"<?php echo $ccheck...
```

(consejo: olvídate de este estilo horrible de código embebido. No es una buena practica, cuando tu código crezca vas a estar en problemas. Saludos.)